# Как читать URL во Vuejs?

Tags: vue.js

У меня есть непонятная немного для меня задача. Есть страница, на которой есть 5 групп радиокнопок. Пользователь может их отметить, и тогда будет выведен контент. Но есть кейс, в котором по специальному урлу (например .com/?radio1=cas&radio2=des) Пользователь должен попасть на страницу, в которой эти кнопки сразу должно быть отмечены. Есть у кого идеи, какую документацию покопать, или как сделать?

То есть другими словами, мне нужно, чтобы урл, отмечал данные из даты. Например если есть переменная radio1, значит брать ее значение и подставлять в дату. Хотя я могу ошибаься, возможно есть другой путь

Comment: при открытии страницы, извлечите данные из urla `location.search` и отметьте нужные чекбоксы

Comment: [`vue-router`](https://router.vuejs.org/) в помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В router.js делаете примерно вот так (ну или вешаете хук на конкретный маршрут).

```
....
import store from '@/store';
....


....
....

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (Object.keys(to.query).length !== 0) store.commit('setRadioData', to.query);
  next({ name: to.name, params: to.params });
});
```

В Vuex проверяете что там вам пришло, записываете в state.
В компоненте v-model для радио кнопок берете из computed свойства с сеттером и геттером.

Если что-то не знаете как сделать пишите в коментах - распишу подробнее.